# How to get Apple music artwork using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, apple-music

I have an AppleScript which retrieves several properties of the current track playing on apple music but I can't retrieve the artwork

```
if application "Music" is running then
    tell application "Music"
        if player state is playing or player state is paused then
            set currentTrack to current track

            return {get player state} & {get artist of currentTrack} & {get name of currentTrack} & {get album of currentTrack} & {get kind of currentTrack} & {get duration of currentTrack} & {player position} & {get genre of current track} & {get id of current track}
        else
            return "stopped"
        end if
    end tell
else
    return "stopped"
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple i just couldn't find it, so Doug made a very simple script  that you can find [here](https://dougscripts.com/itunes/2014/10/save-current-tracks-artwork/) and that i reworked a bit it save the current track artwork to the same location as the script and name it tmp.jpg or png

```
tell application "Music"

    try

        if player state is not stopped then

            set alb to (get album of current track)

            tell artwork 1 of current track

                if format is JPEG picture then

                    set imgFormat to ".jpg"

                else

                    set imgFormat to ".png"

                end if

            end tell

            set rawData to (get raw data of artwork 1 of current track)

        else

            return

        end if

    on error

        display dialog "Problem getting track info." buttons {"OK"}

        return

    end try

end tell


--get current path
tell application "Finder"
    set current_path to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell

--create path to save image as jpg or png
set newPath to ((current_path as text) & "tmp" & imgFormat) as text

try
    --create file
    tell me to set fileRef to (open for access newPath with write permission)

    --overwrite existing file
    write rawData to fileRef starting at 0

    tell me to close access fileRef

on error m number n

    log n

    log m

    try

        tell me to close access fileRef

    end try

end try
```